# Monitor outbound connections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, connection, network-monitoring

How I can monitor outbound connection that are made from my server along with the program/application which has made the connection request?
I have tried using the below command and I am not much familiar with it so not sure if the output is all outbound connections:

```
netstat -nputw | awk '{if (!match($4, /:443/)&&!match($4, /:80/)&&!match($4, /:82/)&&!match($4, /:8080/)&&!match($4, /:22/)) print $0}'
```

Here 443,82,22,80 are my server listener port.

Answer (score 0):

[nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#readme) is an excellent `top` command like tool, but showing network activity grouped by processes. Should help you quite a lot especially if your server does not have tons of activity.

Comment: I tried with this command. Do want to add anything?  # netstat -nputw | awk '{if (!match($4, /:443/)&&!match($4, /:80/)&&!match($4, /:82/)&&!match($4, /:8080/)&&!match($4, /:22/)) print $0}'   (Here 443,82,22,80 are my server listener port)

Comment: netstat -naputw | awk '{if (!match($4, /:443/)&&!match($4, /:80/)&&!match($4, /:82/)&&!match($4, /:8080/)&&!match($4, /:22/)&&!match($5, /10.3.1.6/)&&!match($5, /(192|10|172).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)((:[0-9]+)*)/)) print $0}'